# React : How to apply the state change to all instances of a Component, even if the state of any one instance of component is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a table with multiple tds. Each td is a component of its own. How do I implement the functionality such that even if state of one of the td is changed, that state change should apply to all other td components.

S

Answer (score 0):

You would pass a prop into each td that is tied to state in a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to dig into React state management with Redux or Context.